# cvs: working revision vs repository revision?

Tags: version-control, cvs

When I do a cvs status, I see working revision and repository revision numbers.
What is the difference between the two, or rather, what do they mean?

Answer (score 2):

the *working revision* is just the revision you are currently using. the *repository revision* is the revision currently in the repository.

basically, if the *repository revision* is larger than your *working revision*, someone has committed changes to that file, and perhaps you should update your version, or you may end up with a conflict if you try to commit your own changes at a later time.

Comment: Right. But why would anyone still have to use CVS nowadays?

Comment: Granted, vanilla CVS sucks but being a CVSNT user I have yet to find a compelling enough reason to switch to anything else.

Comment: I'm working on a project that uses ancient code.. from like 2002 or even earlier?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, that makes sense... except:
Say I have a file A.java, latest revision is 1.10.
I do a cvs up -r1.9 A.java.
cvs status shows both working and repository revision to be 1.9...

What's going on??

Comment: cvs up -r1.9 means you're updating your files to release 1.9, so the repository version would be the version in release 1.9. (ie not 1.10, as that exists in -r1.10 i would assume)

Comment: so you need to do an 
cvs update -A to get  the latest and greatest and clear your 1.9 tag